# passing values from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

HTML CODE

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="button" id="id1">
    <input type="button" id="id2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
totalqty=0;


    $("#id1").click(function(){

        qty1=qty1+1;
        totalqty=totalqty+1;
        $("#result").html(qty1);
    });

    $("#id2").click(function(){
        qty2=qty2+1;
        totalqty=totalqty+1;
        $("#result").html(qty2);
    });
```

Can you give me some tips on how I can send the qty1, qty2 and totalqty to my php file, after I click the submit button. Before I send it to the php file, I need to check first if the button is already clicked. If not, no qty will be send to the phpfile. I need to send the exact number of qty based on how many times you clicked the button.

Comment: on your `phpfile.php` use $_POST because you used `<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">` let php process the logic section which is adding and not javascript

Comment: @DrixsonOseña, Im familiar <form action="phpfile.php" method="post">, and maybe your right that php should be the one to get for the total. but my main problem here is how can I send the exact number of qty based on how many times you clicked the button. And another scenario is that what if I clicked both.

Comment: As for starting you can always use `<input type="hidden" name="qty1">` and append this using jquery, just remember put it in your form.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to add `qty` as `<input type="hidden" id="qty1" name="qty1" />` to your form. They will be invisible as your variables, and will be sent to the server as form fields. To access their values from Javascript, use `$("#qty1").value()`

Comment: okei.. But I need to track it from the button id="result". From the id="result, that's where I will track if the buttons where clicked. And what if I had a lot of buttons to be clicked, is it still advisable to use <input type="hidden" id="qty1" name="qty1" />??

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

This is easy to implement using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, but it's also available using regular JavaScript.

If you choose to use the jQuery implementation then your can look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Here's a basic example:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'target.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data  : {
       'foo' : 10
   }
}).done(function()
{
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

You then use the back-end to handle the response, let's for example assume that you send an object of parameters whera one key is named foo and the value is 10, then you could fetch it like this (if the code is PHP):

```
$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : "";
```

Using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function:

```
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
totalqty=0;

$("#id1").click(function(){
    qty1=qty1+1;
    totalqty=totalqty+1;
    $("#result").html(qty1);

    get_values(qty1);
});

$("#id2").click(function(){
    qty2=qty2+1;
    totalqty=totalqty+1;
    $("#result").html(qty2);

    get_values(qty2);
});

function get_values(qty_val) {
    $.post(
        'get_values.php', // url of your php who will receive the values
        { post_variable_name: qty_val }, // your post variables here
        function(data) {
            // call back function
            $("#result").html(data); // see what does your get_value.php echoes via html
            console.log(data); // see it via console in inspect element
        }
    );
}
```

and in your php that will recieve the values, just retrieve using $_POST:

```
<?php
$qty_val = '';
if(isset($_POST['post_variable_name'])) {
   $qty_val = $_POST['post_variable_name'];
   echo $qty_val;
}
?>
```

Comment: let me try it first. :)

Comment: sure :) in your callback function you can add $("#result").html(data); to confirm the values recieved by your php file.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form>
    <input name="id1" type="button" id="id1" />
    <input name="id2" type="button" id="id2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

JS

```
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
totalqty=0;

$("#id1").click(function(){
    qty1=qty1+1;
    totalqty=totalqty+1;
    $("#result").html(qty1);
});

$("#id2").click(function(){
    qty2=qty2+1;
    totalqty=totalqty+1;
    $("#result").html(qty2);
});


$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // prevent the default event
    event.preventDefault();

    // check first if the totalqty. You can add more checks here
    if ( totalqty === 0 ) {

        // usually show some kind of error message here
        alert('No quantity selected!');

        // this prevents the form from submitting
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'phpfile.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                quantity1: qty1,
                quantity2: qty2,
                totalQuantity: totalqty
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            alert( "success" );

            $('#status').html("Successfully saved!");
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log(data);

            alert( "error" );

            $('#status').html("Successfully saved!");
        });
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$qty1 = isset($_POST['quantity1']) ? $_POST['quantity1'] : "";
$qty2 = isset($_POST['quantity2']) ? $_POST['quantity2'] : "";
$total = isset($_POST['totalQuantity']) ? $_POST['totalQuantity'] : "";
```

Sorry, i can't test it, but it should work

For more detailed you could have a look to the [jQuery Learning Center - Ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) where you can find useful examples to work with ajax and forms.